# Windows User Deletion Script

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I need some help with this code. The code, in theory, works however, when the code runs all user profiles apart from the ones in my excluded are deleted. I want the last login profiles to remain within 30 days and users over 30 days to be deleted. I have tried different `AddDays(-)` however the problem remains.

Could anyone help?

```
$ExcludedUsers = "ExcludedFolder"
$LocalProfiles = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { (!$_.Special) -and (!$_.Loaded) -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) }
foreach ($LocalProfile in $LocalProfiles) {
    if (!($ExcludedUsers -like $LocalProfile.LocalPath.Replace("C:\Users\", ""))) {
        $LocalProfile | Remove-WmiObject
        Write-host $LocalProfile.LocalPath, "Profile Has Been Deleted” -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: So it is only the data-filtering part that doesn't work?

Comment: Are you executing this script just to regain HDD space or to clean-up user profile from that PC?  Because, this will not properly remove the user profiles and may cause issues if user is trying to login to the same PC. Better to use Group policy to delete the older profiles.

Comment: @DillyB, can you elaborate more on how this isn't the proper way to delete profiles?

Comment: Deleting a profile should be clearing the user folder from c:\users\ and registry entries created for that profile. Otherwise user folder will be deleted and registry entries along with the user settings will be available in the registry. I have done the following steps no. of times during windows 7 for solving internet explorer and outlook issues. 1. Restart the pc. 2. Login as different user. 3. Open users and groups from control panel. Select the profile and delete it.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes it is just the data filtering which doesn't seem to work. I have tried various numbers with minus and non-minus but it doesn't want to play ball. If I type 0 it will delete all profiles apart from the excluded folders.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes I just want to gain HDD space on various computers. At some point, the code is going to be used in group policy which will be an automation task once a month to clear HDD space on overused computers. On most computers, the users won't sign in for 2-3 months which causes HDD space to be used up.  I would delete the user's manually to save space but it is a long task to do on 100s of computers.

Comment: @DillyB, this is all that's needed for that. The CIM object properties tie everything to the account and all that's needed is the call to remove it, just how the OP has done; this includes registry settings, folder paths, etc.. Only would suggest to use the newer CIM cmdlets rather than the deprecated WMI ones though.

Comment: I am getting an error using WMI method. ```Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile |
    Where-Object {
        (!$_.Special) -and 
        (!$_.Loaded) -and
        ($_.LastUseTime -lt $(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-30))
        }``` try using CIM method to verify the query works. Thanks!

Comment: @DillyB I tried this method and it didn't work it deleted newly created users on the machine and some of the excluded files. haha.

Comment: The above lines doesn't have any command to delete the user profiles. I executed this query and got the list of profiles which are not used in 30 days.  No clue!